# Are there definitive, unambiguous terms for hexagon tile orientations?

Tags: tilemap, terminology, hexagonal-grid

I have been working on a tile map editor and plan to support two orientations for hexagons. I have seen various terms used, but these all seem ambiguous to me.

- Horizontal, Vertical (ambiguous: does this mean they line up horizontally, or stack horizontally?)
- Flat, Pointed (ambiguous: Are they flat on the sides or top and bottom?)

I would like to find **unambiguous** terms for the following two orientations for hexagons -- ideally, these would be **definitive** and **succinct** (I could refer to these as "Flat on Top" and "Pointed on Top" but would prefer something more technical and authoritative).

[image: Flat-Top] [image: Pointed-Top]

**Edit:** I was holding out for something more technical, but it's hard to argue with Amit. For me, "pointed" sounds more formal than "pointy," so I am going to use the following (a decision reinforced by DMGregory's answer): **Flat-top** and **Pointed-Top**.

Comment: This may boil down to opinion as to which terms are most appropriate, as I don't know of any official convention. [The most authoritative source I know of on hex grids in games, Red Blob Games's amazing reference sheet, uses "flat topped" and "pointy topped"](http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/) similar to what you suggest.

Comment: @DMGregory Make it an answer. I'd definitely consider Amit an authority on the matter, and those terms sound clear to me.

Comment: I don't know where I picked up those terms; it was probably usenet a long time ago, but I can't find a source. I wanted something unambiguous for the orientation of the hexagon separate from the arrangement of hexagons on a map. Looking at a *single hexagon*, terms like “staggered columns” don't work, but terms like “flat top” do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While I don't know of any truly official convention for classifying these, in the mathematical sense, I'll take [Anko](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/7804/anko)'s advice and write up what I do know...

[Amit Patel](https://twitter.com/redblobgames) ([Red Blob Games](http://www.redblobgames.com/)) wrote what I'd consider [the definitive guide to using hexagonal grids in games](http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/). This guide uses the nomenclature:

- flat topped
- pointy topped

So while it's not super technical-sounding, I think it's as close to authoritative as we're likely to find. The terms are also understandable and unambiguous even without specialized technical knowledge, which is a huge win.

If you want something less informal, you could try names along the lines of "staggered columns" vs "staggered rows" but I think this is substantially less clear.

Comment: As a programmer I would prefer the "staggered columns/rows" terminology, because it hints at how to implement it (although those terms would have been a bad choice for the guide you linked, because it also explains implementations where thinking in these terms is counter-prodictive).

Comment: @Philipp I think that comment should also be developed into a new answer. It is actually quite a good suggestion

Comment: Myself I'd avoid the terms for that same reason: they hint at a way to implement it which often adds more special cases than alternative methods, and so may actually represent an antipattern to avoid reinforcing through terminology. ;) In my experience, my hex code got a lot cleaner when I stopped thinking in terms of even/odd rows & columns.

Comment: My examples are both of the staggered variety, but the same hexagons can be arranged as a matrix (which looks more like a diamond) or even a hexagon of the opposite orientation. So I think those terms are good for the maps rather the hexagons themselves.

Comment: (2016) Apple now uses “flat” and “pointy” in [iOS SpriteKit](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sktilesettype/).